# Is my code safe from SQL injection? Simple Sessions login

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first login system using SESSIONS.
Just wondering, if it's safe for SQL injection?

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(isset($username, $password)) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $ousername = stripslashes($username);
        $uusername = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($username));
        $opassword = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
    } else {
        $uusername = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $opassword = $password;
    }   
    $req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.$uusername.'"');
    $dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);

    if($dn['password']==$opassword and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
    {
        $form = false;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];        

    echo 'Logged in m8';
    } else {
        $form = true;
        $message = 'The username or password is incorrect.';
    }
} else {
    $form = true;
}
if($form)
{ 
if(isset($message)) {
    echo '<div class="message">'.$message.'</div>';
}           
?>
```

I was getting a SQL injection before on my highscores script, so I was wondering if my simple sessions login script have any, I'm 40% there is one..
What usually causes SQL injections? 
Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call `mysql_connect`?

Comment: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: It is. But using [PDO with prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) is much easier than mysql_ babysitting and manual escaping.

Comment: I don't get the difference between PDO and mysql_, really, what is the main reason to use it ? I call mysql at connect.php (I use require for the file)

Comment: Magic quotes, mysql_* functions.... Please use PDO. It is 2013 now. Let's embrace the new improved more secure apis.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and will get remove. Why you want to insist continuing deprecated functions?

Comment: **Either its safe or not it wont work in php 5.5 ...** however you can use [this function form here in your common sense's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14112684/1723893) its pretty much same what pdo does and safe too

Comment: Well I find PDO pretty hard, but thanks Ill try it out - get used to it.

Comment: Implicit in this code is that you're storing your passwords plaintext; you shouldn't be doing that. At minimum, you should be hashing your passwords with a salt.

Comment: This belongs on codereview, not on SO...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1 (relinked). If you don't know it's safe, it's not. Stop wasting time :(

Comment: `*sigh*` magic quotes are real and a developer *have* to take care of them. PDO and prepared statments aren't silver bullet, they have no placeholder for identifiers for example. mysql will be present on shared hostings for at least 5 years. What we really need is to get rid of **whatever** raw API calls in our code, not of mysql_* only. It is not API but only knowledge that can make your code secure - one can write insecure code with PDO as well. But who cares on this God blessed site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your code is okay, your *idea* of protection is wrong
mysql_real_escape_string does not protect from injections. It does **format strings.** 
As long as you have your strings properly formatted, they are safe.

The problem begins when you're trying to use the same function to format non-strings - a numbers for example.
It become totally useless and your SQL - vulnerable.

So, you can keep with your current code but in the future, as soon as you will need to use another query part - you will need to format it differently. Here is a set of full rules: [In PHP when submitting strings to the database should I take care of illegal characters using htmlspecialchars() or use a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-database-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-cha/2995163#2995163)

And of course **do not escape password**! If i have a password like `wef5623'sdf` - it will never let me in!

By the way, I have no idea why you're using SO much variables for just a single value - $_POST['username'], $username, $uusername, $ousername - what's all this?

Comment: +1 this answer is informative and makes sense ...

Answer (score -3):

i would change 
     `$opassword = $password;`

to

```
 $opassword = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

sql injection can be done via password fields too.

Comment: they don't use password in the SQL. So, no SQL injection via password field.

Comment: -1 of course..agreed with(@YourCommonSense) i don't think anyone uses plan text in password isnt it ? i dont know how one can use sql injection by [`sha1("' or '1'='1' /* '");`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KRsckw)