# get_magic_quotes_gpc() and mysql_real_escape_string - security

Tags: security, function, mysql-real-escape-string

i am practicing php and I am puzzled while interpreting a function to escape dangerous sql characters. i want to know how it works especially the $value in the second if. its quiet puzzling for me to understand the actual flow of function.

```
function quote_smart($value, $handle) {

   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $value = stripslashes($value);
   }

   if (!is_numeric($value)) {
       $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
   }
   return $value;
}
```

Comment: [There are **NO dangerous characters**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2995163/285587).

Comment: @YourCommonSense *blink* I may be low on coffee, but in what way does an answer saying you should escape your characters, not remove them contradict anything in this function that escapes characters and not removes them? Parameterised queries would be better of course, but...

Comment: you are probably not understanding what im trying to say.. actually i this is a part of my code

Comment: actually i passing parameters entered by user in a form and then after connection to database in $handle and the passing inputs as $value im just concerned about that particular part of code that passes variables  $uname = quote_smart($uname, $db_handle);
  $pword = quote_smart($pword, $db_handle);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the code does is basically;

- First it removes the effect of [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) if and only if it's enabled in the server. It should not be since magic_quotes has been deprecated for a while (and removed entirely in new PHP versions).
- Second, it encloses all non numeric values of `$value` in single quotes, and escapes the value using `mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid SQL injection in your value string.

Using recent versions of PHP, this method should not exist at all, since `magic_quotes_gpc` should never be enabled, and you'd be using `PDO` or `MySQLi` parameterized queries that do not need their values to be escaped.

Comment: if i am passing a value like O'corner in particular function then what will it pass to sql as query ...............$uname = quote_smart($uname, $db_handle);

  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE L1 = $uname;
  $result = mysql_query($SQL);

Comment: @user2591221 You'd probably use it as `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='.quote_smart("O'Corner");` which would give a valid MySQL query similar to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='O\'Corner'`. As compared to parameterized queries, building queries from strings is comparatively easy to get wrong though.

Comment: if magic quote is removed from updated versions of php what code we now use instead ov it

Comment: @user2591221 If you properly use `mysql_real_escape_string`, you don't need magic quotes. It was added to begin with as a misguided attempt to prevent SQL injection if you forgot to escape your SQL, but since it's _easily_ bypassed by a hacker it's not very useful on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't "escape dangerous sql characters". It does format `$value` as a correct mySQL literal. But does it wrong,

- because it deals with `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` while it shouldn't.
- and it does some magic, trying to format either numbers or strings
- and it's intended to format values inserted  into query directly, not via placeholder.

Correct version have to be

```
function quote_string($value, $handle)
{
    return = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
}
```

and it should be used only to process a *placeholder*.

While magic quotes have to be dealt with in a bootstrap file, for **all** input values, not only ones going into query, though for compatibility purpose only.